# Journey Builder vs Automation Builder studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

Need some direction on the best way to approach this use case in SFMC:

Sweepstakes campaign that runs for 60 days.  Once someone enters they receive a confirmation of entry.  That's the easy part.

From there they will receive a re-entry reminder email that provides them a link to go to a landing page and re-enter the sweeps.  Here's where it gets tricky.  The email content for the reminder will feature a different 'hero' video each day that is specific to that day of the week.  (the implication here is that this can't be a standard journey builder because I need the person that enters to not start at the beginning of the journey)

i.e. if it's day 20, the person that entered on day 1 will receive the same re-entry reminder email as the person who entered on day 19.

Comment: Could you use ampscript to perform a lookup in a DE that contains the respective content?

What might help in understanding this is how many different 'hero' videos are there? are there 60 or just 7 (one for each day of the week)

Comment: There's going to be 60 unique 'hero' videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expound on Lukas' answer - Rather than handwrite each of these, I would place them inside of a DE and then have the ampscript in the email perform a lookup to that DE to find the appropriate content area:

(If only the URL/IMG changes - you could set these in the DE and use variables rather than build a content area for each)

Example below.

**DE: (Content_DE)**

Date         |   ContentID
2017/12/06   |    102050
2017/12/07    |   102051
etc...

**AMPScript:**

```
%%[
SET @Today = NOW()
SET @Contentid = LOOKUP('Content_DE', 'ContentID', 'Date', @Today)
]%%
%%=ContentArea(@Contentid)=%%
```

---

**EDIT**
Content Builder requires you to use the Content Block AMPScript calls.  See below for the two options:

Content Block by Key (references external key of Content Block)
    `%%=ContentBlockbyKey("myContentBlock")=%%`

Content Block by Name (Name of the content block to return - need full path)
    `%%=ContentBlockByName("Content Builder\Weekly Portfolio")=%%`

To utilize these, you would need to include either the name or the key instead of the ContentID in your DE/SQL.

Comment: This makes things a lot more scalable.  But I'm getting an error `Invalid value specified for function parameter.
 Function Name: ContentArea
 Parameter Name: ContentID
 `

Comment: Are you using Content builder?

Comment: Yes.  I've modeled the DE like this:  `Date` (as Date) | `ContentID` (numeric) | `url` (as string).  I've also created HTML content block with `customer key` to match `ContentID`

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  To confirm - I would need to still create the content blocks but would be able to lookup based on date to dynamically generate "today's" content?  Right now I have the `contentID` matching the `Customer Key`

Answer (score 3):

I would do it using [**ContentArea('ID')**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentarea.htm) AMPScript function:

Build 7 separate content areas, containing HTML for the hero of the email, and select each of them, based on the weekday.

`SET @today = Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()), "dddd")`

Then build IF / ELSE IF which switches between the different content areas, based on the value of `@today`

EDIT:

You might not even need to use a DE to map dates and content IDs. Imagine this scenario. You add a number field to your sendable DE, which you increment for each email sendout. This field is then read into the email, into the `@JourneyDay` - then you can use it to retrieve the content areas, named: Day1, Day2, Day3 and so on.

`%%=ContentBlockByName(Concat("Content Builder\Day",@JourneyDay))=%%`

Comment: I can manually name the content areas and preload the email to pull the content based on @today, right?  

Is there any issue with having an email with too much ampscript (for deliverability)

NOTE: There's going to be a total of 79 content areas.  1 for each day.

Comment: Yes you can use the name of the content area to retrieve it. But then the right function is ContentAreaByName